# How to create a variable for path and use it on making a new directory in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to use a variable for the path, instead of typing it manually

Instead of this

```
#create a folder 
New-Item -Path 'D:\Test\New_folder' -ItemType Directory
```

to have something like this

```
$path='D:\Test'
```

#create a folder with a var

```
New-Item -Path '$path\New_folder' -ItemType Directory
```

But it is not working. I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Is't's not working because of the single-quotes you use. That way, `$path` will not get expanded. Either use double-quotes `"` or better, use the [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) cmdlet as in `Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath 'New_Folder'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to use double quotes `"` to allow var to expend :

```
$yourPath='D:\Test'
New-Item -Path "$yourPath\New_folder" -ItemType Directory
```